# How can I display error messages in android with a custom class?

Tags: android, class, message

As the title suggests, I'm trying to create a class that will display an error message in android and my reasoning is that, instead of creating a pop up wherever it was needed as well as declaring the preset error strings  in the MainActivity, it would be cleaner to create a separate class containing the preset info and the code necessary to actually display the message. The only parameter it would need would be the actual exception.

The way I tried to achieve this was by extending the AlertDialog.Builder class as follows:

```
public class showError extends AlertDialog.Builder
{
    private enum exString
    {
        UnknownHostException, IOException,
        ConnectException, Exception,
        NoTimeTablesFoundException
    }

    private String UHE;
    private String IOE;
    private String CE;
    private String NTTFE;
    private String CNFE;
    private String title;
    private String E;

    private String message ="";
    private String exception="";

    Context cxt;
    exString enumExc;

    public showError(Exception ex, Context cxt)
    {
        super(cxt);
        this.cxt = cxt;

        initString();    

        try
        {
            exception =  ex.getClass().getName().toString();
            exception = exception.substring(exception.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
            enumExc = exString.valueOf(exception);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException err)
        {
            enumExc = exString.valueOf("Exception");
        }

        setType();

        setTitle(title);
        setMessage(message);
        setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {

            }
        });

        setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);


        //show();
    }


    private void initString()
    {
        String UHE = cxt.getString(R.string.errorUHE);
        String IOE = cxt.getString(R.string.errorIOE);
        String CE = cxt.getString(R.string.errorCE);
        String NTTFE = cxt.getString(R.string.errorNTTFE);
        String title = cxt.getString(R.string.errorTitle);
        String E = cxt.getString(R.string.errorUnknown);
    }

    private void setType()
    {
        switch (enumExc)
        {
            case UnknownHostException:
            { message = UHE; break; }

            case IOException:
            { message = IOE; break; }

            case ConnectException:
            { message = CE; break; }

            case NoTimeTablesFoundException:
            { message = NTTFE; break; }

            case Exception:
            { message = E + exception; break; }
        }
    }
}
```

The way I would like for this to work is:

```
new showError(whateverException, this);
```

However, for some reason I don't understand, it constantly gives a WindowLeaked exception?
I commented the show() command in the class and, instead, started using

```
 new showError(whateverException, this).show();
```

and this seems to work sometimes but this also throws the WindowLeaked exception from time to time.

First of all, can someone shed some light as to why, since it is the same context, does it make a difference where I call the show command (in the constructor of the class itself, or by calling the .show() method)? 
Why does calling show in the constructor always throw an exception, whereas calling it by using .show() of the instantiated class sometimes work?

I understand that this exception is thrown when the activity that creates the dialog ends before the dialog is dismissed. Is this correct? 
And if it is, when I try using MainActivity as the context, am I supposed to believe that the MainActivity ends? How can it end while the app is still running?

ALso, if these dialogs are asynchronous (they are on a seperate thread from the UI thread so as to not block the UI thread, is my understanding correct?) how come they need to be dismissed before the activity ends? 
Because, it seems, in order for my code to work, I would actually need to have the app wait for the dialog to be dismissed (sort of how you cannot use the main form of a Windows desktop app while a MessageBox is being displayed), but it is my understanding that android doesn't do that by design.

Even more confusing is if instead of using this approach, I create and show an AlertDialog.Builder in every catch block, that seems to work perfectly each time... why?

Second, I'm not exactly trying to find out how to fix the flaws of my design but what I actually am looking for is understanding why my design is flawed  and what approach would be appropriate to achieve what I want?

Or better yet, what is the industry standard for handling exceptions and displaying the appropriate error messages to the user so that he knows what has gone wrong (whenever possible)?

Thank you for your time and excuse the lengthy read.